# Populating a "created" column in a spring data entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "created", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Basic
public Timestamp getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```

I have this entity and I would like for MySQL to provide the created timestamp.  I've tried adding `@GeneratedValue` and `nullable = true` and it still fails when saving saying the value cannot be null.

I understand my entity is passing null because that's the default value so MySQL is throwing an error because I'm trying to pass null and it's not set as a NULl field.

However, is it possible for me to work around this on a java object level?  Say, not submit the `created` column when the entity is saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`@PrePersist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) handler to initialize the field. The initialization will be done prior to the entity being saved, thus avoiding the null pointer exception.

```
@PrePersist
protected void beforeCreate() {
    if(created == null)
        created = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```